# Linking to a File Server ApEx

Tags: oracle, glassfish, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Could you help me, please?

Looking online, I found that you can put the files in the Apex image folder and call them from there with the following sentence:

```
<a href="#IMAGE_PREFIX#"file.pdf"> Download pdf </a>
```

or

```
<a href="/i/file.pdf"> Download pdf </a>
```

The amount of files I need to put in that folder is approximately 1 TB so I think it is not the best option to put them in the folder, besides that an update of Oracle files can be deleted.

I found the following:
It's not recommended to store your own files under the Apex images folder, because they could be overwritten during Apex upgrades. Instead, you can define your own logical directory e.g. / myfiles / on the app server pointing to a different location and then reference that instead like this:

```
<a href="/myfiles/file.pdf"> Download pdf </a>
```

Create the directory as follow

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY myfiles AS 'C:\test';
```

How do I define the logical directory in the app server? I'm using Glassfish.

Comment: Creating an Oracle DIRECTORY object is unrelated to your app server's ability to serve files.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pretty old, but relevant [guide](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/serving-static-content-on-weblogic-and-glassfish/) written by Colm Divilly. You'll only need the descriptor file for Glassfish in your case. Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
  <!-- This element specifies the context path the static resources are served from -->
  <context-root>/myfiles</context-root>
  <!-- This element specifies the location on disk where the static resources are located -->
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/* dir="c:/test"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

Check the Windows path to the resources, it might need to be corrected. I rarely work with Windows for deployments.

A few other things:

- Typically, in the scenario you've described, I would put a web server
  like Apache HTTPD or Nginx to serve up the the static files.
- ORDS support for Glassfish has been deprecated.